# difference between a DC motor and gear motor

Tags: motor, dc

Isnt DC motor the same as gear motor? Because what is the use of dc motor without gears?

Comment: What is the use of motor without gears?  Fans, propellers, lots of other things; I answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DC motor is not the same as a "gear motor" - a "gear motor" may be an AC or DC motor coupled with a gearbox or transmission. A gear motor adds mechanical gears to alter the speed/torque of the motor for an application. Usually such an addition is to reduce speed and increase torque. A DC motor without gears is useful in many applications, for example the simple fan. Contrast that with the motor that operates the turntable in your microwave, a gearbox there reduces the speed so your food isn't thrown against the interior wall.

For more information, check the Wikipedia on [DC Motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor).

Comment: So basically a gear coupled dc motor is a gear motor and it uses the same battery pack as a dc motor wud have used?

Comment: Sure, there's no reason the motor driving a gearbox has to necessarily be different. Obviously it must meet the requirements of the gearbox plus the load together.

Comment: @user35997 A gear coupled DC motor, a gear coupled BLDC motor, or a gear coupled AC motor: Those are all "*gear motors*". That term is merely a simplification and generalization, especially for the hobbyist / DIY community, to insulate them from nitty gritty details.